# Deploying Search Centre via Feature

Tags: search

Is it possible to deploy search centre via a Feature?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a feature event receiver to create it as a site collection or a subsite. I tend to have my search centers as site collections.

```
public class DefaultEventReceiver : SPFeatureReceiver {
    public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties) {
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate() {
            //as a site collection
            SPWebApplication app = SPWebApplication.Lookup(new Uri("http://xyz"));              
            SPSite site = app.Sites.Add("http://xyz",title,desc,1033,"SRCHCEN#0",...);
            //as a subsite
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://xyz")) {
                web = site.RootWeb.Webs.Add("xyz","xyz","xyz",web.Language,"SRCHCEN#0",...);
            }           
        });
    }
}
```

Replace "SRCHCEN#0" with another the template name if it is different version of sharepoint.